# Intermittent segfault using libsqlite3, "error 4 in libsqlite3.so.0.8.6"

Tags: c, linux, sqlite, embedded

I have some C code running on an embedded device which is initialised at startup. The code queries a small database with a simple name/value table. I noticed that around 1 time in 20 the code fails to run, after adding in some logging I found the following message:

```
 user.info kernel: [   47.983041] my_code[2237]: segfault at bf87601f ip b78b7115 sp bf8758f0 error 4 in libsqlite3.so.0.8.6[b7872000+51000]
```

The function that handles the database query is:

```
void my_db_query(char* my_setting, char* my_result)
{

sqlite3 *db;
if(sqlite3_open("/tmp/system.db", &db) != 0){
    printf("Failed to Open DB\n");
}

char query_string[100];
memset(query_string, 0, 100);
char* query_one = "select value from setting where name=\"";
char* query_two = "\";";
char db_result[256];
int ret;
strcat(query_string, query_one);
strcat(query_string, my_setting);
strcat(query_string, query_two);

sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_string, 1000, &stmt, 0);
if (ret != SQLITE_OK ){
    printf("Error preparing\n");
}

while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    strcpy(db_result,(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
    strncpy(my_result,db_result, strnlen(db_result, 256));

}
sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

I'm using sqlite3 version 3.6.11, and I'm not able to change that version as I don't have permissions. Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like replacing the line `strncpy(my_result,db_result, strnlen(db_result, 256));` with `strcpy(my_result,db_result);` has done the trick, as `db_result` wasn't zeroed before the copy.